# How to initialise table row in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have table layout with table row.

```
TableLayout TableHeader = new TableLayout(this);
TableRow HeaderRow[]=null;
HeaderRow[0] = new TableRow(this);
```

i want to use table row in array format as per above but if i use this its shows (null pointer access:) error.how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array HeaderRow is null, instead it should be:

```
TableRow HeaderRow[]=new TableRow[size];
```

where size is the number of elements of array.

Comment: ok thank u very much now its works,,is it possible to use for layout(for example:RelativeLayout one = new RelativeLayout[100];)

Comment: yes, but a TableLayout may have  only TableRow as Childs. amd Tp declare array of relativelayouts, do following:  RelativeLayout one[]=new RelativeLayout[100];